# Can't get internet working on any Linux distro

Tags: linux, internet

Recently I've been getting into Linux inside virtualbox and have become quite fond of its different distros. Finally after some time i decided to install Ubuntu on my second hard drive so that i could fully experience it without Windows running in the background. The only problem was, my internet wasn't working on it. It didn't list my internet anywhere on it. I then tried SliTaz Linux and it didn't work, Then DSL, Lubuntu, Tiny Core, etc. I tried at least a dozen Linux distros and none of them would work. None of them showed my internet connection. Some of them wouldn't even let me try to add new connections.

I have an optiplex 780 Desktop, I'm not Ethernet connected. I use this big blue/black thing that has "Linksys" on the side that connects via 4 small ports on the bottom back on my computer to receive wifi. The blue/black thing has a blue center core, then 3 black peg-legs holding it up.

Comment: are ANY wifi networks showing up?  or is yours just missing?  You might need a driver.  Look for a part number on the linksys device and look online for a linux driver that matches your distro

Comment: Many of the featherweight/lightweight distros don't come with an extensive collection of drivers, and some drivers aren't included with some distros by default because they aren't free/open source.  You will need temporary Internet access via Ethernet cable or another computer.  Check the Linksys website for Linux drivers.  Beyond that, it's a search of repositories, distro user communities, etc. to locate drivers.  Unfortunately, it is one of the shortcomings of Linux (but it's getting better all the time).

Comment: @RusselUhl its not showing any networks

Comment: @fixer1234 im not able to connect my computer to ethernet since we have very short ethernet cables and my router in downstairs and my desktop is upstairs. Also i am unable to have any other computers to connect to.

Comment: The only way you're likely to solve the problem is to get on the Internet somewhere.  Maybe temporarily move a computer?  Ask a friend?  buy a long cable?  Another approach: most distros offer a DVD that they will mail to you for a small contribution.  One of the more complete distros (like Mint), is likely to have the needed driver bundled.  A live session could then be used to find and download what you need for the distro you want to use.

Comment: Well the truth is...im actually 12 yrs old so i cant buy longer cables-buy a dvd from the distributer-ask a friend(im the only kid i know who has their own computer)-and my computer is currently in a very awkward position, for me to get it out i would have to move my entire desk, and my desktop takes up half my room and it took 3 guys to put it in, and my parents arents going to help me move it just to get it to the downstairs router to connect it via ethernet. And PS just because im 12, STILL TAKE ME SERIOUSLY, i know alot more than you think.

Comment: Also i dont see why i would have to buy a live CD from them since thats how installed the OS's in the first place, the only problem is that i only have 700mb cds and most of the OSs are over 700 mb. Also the reason i say this is because the only way for me to get ubuntu was to install a really old iso of it to the cd, then install that to the drive, then update ubuntu from the drive(i need internet for that). but going back to me buying a dvd, instead of me buying a dvd from them that would cost a ton, i just ordered a pack of 50 4.7 GB dvds, But buring the isos to them wont solve my internet.

Comment: Are you currently running Windows and your Linksys WiFi adapter works in Windows (so you can access the Internet there)? If so, that's a route to either download drivers or download a "loaded" distro that comes bundled with the driver. If your main reason for downloading lightweight distros was that you only had CDs, the DVDs will hold pretty much any distro, and many come with a full assortment of drivers. In the meantime, one CD-sized distro that might work is [Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.org) (solved my similar problem; and no need to install it, runs from RAM).

Comment: One thing that has kept me away from Puppy Linux is its look, im just not to fond of its looks, but i guess if for now its all i can get, i guess i have to. Ill get back to you soon on whether it worked or not. And also yes my linksys wifi thing does work on windows(windows 7).

Comment: @Cubit-Games: remember to "address" your comments so people get alerted to your post.  Yeah, Puppy is a little too cute, but it is a very well done implementation.  BTW, one problem with Puppy, and most of the featherweights, is the same thing you ran into with Ubuntu.  To make them tiny, they use either minimalist or very old, stripped down apps.  Modern browsers can be huge.  You are likely to find that even when you can access the Internet, a lot of sites won't work, particularly if they involve multi-media.

Comment: One other featherweight Linux to check out that might work for you (CD sized): http://www.porteus.org/

Comment: It has been forever sinced i commented and i found out why. First off-DRIVERS. I found installs for the interenet drivers i needed, installed them to a USB, then transfered them to the linux machine. so it just just my drivers, though i did have to use a wifi USB for my second linux machine since my second wifi card did not infact work on it, it is running linux mint, even though my first linux machine is running linux mint aswell, it has the same type of wifi card, just 1 generation lower. So drivers basicly, yea, now i can use any linux OS :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that your wireless adapter driver is not installed. You can look up information about your wireless adapter driver, and how to download the drivers [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx) on Ubuntu's documentation site.

In order to get the adapters you'll have to plug into the back of your router with an Ethernet cord. It's hard to tell without looking at it, but it definitely sounds like your wireless adapter driver is not installed.

Comment: That was it, thank you. but i didnt use ethernet to install them(since the computer is on the second floot, router is on the first floot DX). but what i did was install the drivers to a USB then transfer them to the computer, so yea, all is well. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There can be 2 causes to this. Either your WiFi card in your PC is defective or not connected properly (or you don't have one), or you haven't installed the drivers for your WiFi card. To get drivers for it, search up the name of the WiFi card, followed by drivers for whatever Linux distro you have.